How to do SSR layout with Next-Auth?
I need to get session in SessionProvider, but my project automaticly stay client.
When i do build, i see my page - client (Dynamic).
If i remove next-auth project page stay SSR (static).
How can i use getServerSession in server component? I want to do my project SSR(static).
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Test',
  description: 'Test',
};

export default async function RootLayout({
 children,
}: {
 children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const session = await getServerSession();
  return (
  <html lang="ru">
    <SessionProvider session={session} basePath="/_next_auth/api/auth">
      <Header className={styles.header}>
        <HeaderContent />
      </Header>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        {children}
      </main>
      <Footer className={styles.footer} />
    </SessionProvider>
  </html>
 );
}

I tryed to use getSession, but it dont works because i have basePath in SessionProvider and this function dont work with this.

Move the session provider to separate component.
layout.tsx
import { Metadata } from 'next';
import Header from './Header';
import HeaderContent from './HeaderContent';
import Footer from './Footer';
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth';
import SessionProviderComponent from './SessionProviderComponent'; // Import the new client component
import styles from './styles.module.css';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Test',
  description: 'Test',
};

export default async function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const session = await getServerSession();
  return (
    <html lang="ru">
      <SessionProviderComponent session={session}>
        <Header className={styles.header}>
          <HeaderContent />
        </Header>
        <main className={styles.main}>{children}</main>
        <Footer className={styles.footer} />
      </SessionProviderComponent>
    </html>
  );
}

SessionProviderComponent.tsx
'use client';
import { Session } from 'next-auth';


import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';

type SessionProviderComponentProps = {
  session: Session;
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

export default function SessionProviderComponent({ session, children }: SessionProviderComponentProps) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session} basePath="/_next_auth/api/auth">
      {children}
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}


thanks for your answer, but it dont work fo me
where your import getServerSession? i am import from 'next-auth';

can you also add the error and the next-auth configuration

yes, when i run build my page λ  (Dynamic)  server-rendered on demand using Node.js
my config:
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
async function auth(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
return await NextAuth(req, res, {
providers: [
// my providers
],
callbacks: {
session: async ({ session, token }) => {
if (session?.user) {
session.user.id = token.sub + "";
}
return session;
},
},
});
}
export { auth as GET, auth as POST };

i need ○  (Static)   prerendered as static content
